# RDLC report with one page per order

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

I have a dataset with four entities. Customer, Order, OrderDetail and Item. Each Order has one Customer and many orderDetails. I want to create a report that has a separate page for each order and on that page there should an order id, order date, customer name and below that a table containing all orderDetails.

I tried following this **[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqHsrK7mfy8)**, but when I drag a `List` from the toolbox, onto the report body, the `List` strangely turns into a `Tablix` with a `Rectangle` inside. Then, when I try to insert a `Table`, for the OrderDetails, inside the "List", I get an error from visual studio saying that the tablix has an detail member with inner members.

I also tried searching for other solutions and found some posts suggesting the use of `Groups` in the tablix, but I can't see how I can use that in my scenario. I also couldn't find a documentation on the grouping feature of the tablix.

So, how can I create this kind of report?

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

List just separates each group into a single tablix. So you have to set the row group. In this scenario, you just need to add page break between each group instance, no matter using List or Table.

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, I needed each unit upc per page of the report, i was able to accomplish this by following the steps below, like the video mentioned i didn't use the lists control instead i used the detail section of a table to accomplish my task:

1. Make sure you have a Dataset defined for your report.
2. Add a "Table" control to the report. This seems to be needed in order to iterate the rows in your Dataset.
3. Delete the header row and two of the default columns from the table so that you are left with a single row with a single column.
4. Expand the table to the width of your layout and make it as tall as you will need for your "free form" layout.
5. By default, there is a TextBox inside the table cell. Right-click the empty table cell and choose "delete" to remove that TextBox.
6. Drag a "Rectangle" control into the empty table cell. It seems to automatically "dock" to the width/height of the table cell.
7. Now you should be able to drag the fields from your DataSet (TextBoxes, etc) into the Rectangle to produce the desired layout.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried this way, but when I insert another tablix for the OrderItems into the main tablix I get an error saying "The tablix ‘Tablix2’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner member".

Comment: @Igor yea that happened to me as well, it did not let me add a table with in a detail section, i basically drew a table with using the rectangle and line and added a textbox inside there and then called the desired fields i am not sure if that will work in your case.